# What is the meaning of "nothing's written in stone."?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Rhonda is Alex's fan

> Rhonda: Could I get a picture too?
>
> Alex: Only if you're single.
>
> Rhonda: I've been married 16 years, but **nothing's written in stone.**

Comment: It means that [being married] can change.. that, *something* is subject to change, not guaranteed to be permanent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reference to an event in the bible (Exodus, 31:18) where God presents Moses with the ten commandments, written in tablets of stone.

The ten commandments are a fundamental part of the rules of Judaism, so if you say something is written in tablets of stone, it means that it's a rule that cannot be changed.

"Nothing's written in [tablets of] stone" means that the rules can be changed.

Comment: Interesting. Of course the part about immutability is spot on, but I had always assumed the phrase was more generic, and could refer to, say, a marble statue just as easily as the Ten Commandments. Now I'm [curious](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/14/messages/618.html).